# Unable to hide the action in url

Tags: php, yii2

I want to hide the action view from url I have passed a parameter title.The action view works perfectly but action index does not get executed instead a action view only get called.
Eg: if i request `a/view/yii` it takes to view action, but when i call `a/index` then also view action is called why so?

```
'a/<title:\w+>' => 'a/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `/action/index` matches the template `'a/<title:\w+>'`

you can add additional rule for this route before template:

```
'a' => 'a/index',
'a/<title:\w+>' => 'a/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```